# Enable access form multiple IP mongo v4.0.1

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb v4.0.1 and currently i have the bellow network configurations

```
 net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

I need to enable access for an additional IP address,for this i have added my ip as like the following options

```
bindIp: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,127.0.0.1]
```

And

```
bindIp: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,127.0.0.1
```

Both options are not working and server could not starts

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: @HikeNalbandyan , Unfortunately no,i am accessing from my local system using ssh tonel now.Do you have an issue like this?

Comment: yes, I eventually did bindIp: 0.0.0.0, and made a rule to accept tcp on port 27017 only from given ip's (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). Requests from other ip's are dropped and don't even get to mongo